# how to read dictionary key and values from a nested list and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dictionary with nested dictionary and lists, was trying to output the values for all the keys "name". 
i couldn't figure out the logic to implement on this dictionary

expecting output like

```
test
inside_test
inner_group1
GetFTP
```

Dictionary data:

```
{
  "id": "0ce8df69-016b-1000-ffff-ffffbe50cb53",
  "name": "test",
  "processGroupStatusSnapshot": {
    "name": "test",
    "connectionStatusSnapshots": [],
    "processorStatusSnapshots": [],
    "processGroupStatusSnapshots": [
      {
        "id": "0ce90089-016b-1000-ffff-ffffadb84af5",
        "processGroupStatusSnapshot": {
          "name": "inside_test",
          "connectionStatusSnapshots": [],
          "processorStatusSnapshots": [],
          "processGroupStatusSnapshots": [
            {
              "id": "0ce97287-016b-1000-0000-000056414ae7",
              "processGroupStatusSnapshot": {
                "id": "0ce97287-016b-1000-0000-000056414ae7",
                "name": "inner_group1",
                "connectionStatusSnapshots": [],
                "processorStatusSnapshots": [
                  {
                    "id": "0ce9ca47-016b-1000-0000-0000496a342d",
                    "processorStatusSnapshot": {
                      "id": "0ce9ca47-016b-1000-0000-0000496a342d",
                      "groupId": "0ce97287-016b-1000-0000-000056414ae7",
                      "name": "GetFTP"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "processGroupStatusSnapshots": [],
                "remoteProcessGroupStatusSnapshots": [],
                "inputPortStatusSnapshots": [],
                "outputPortStatusSnapshots": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the nesting level fixed or dynamic? Also, will the other keys be known beforehand, or are those dynamic too?

Comment: nesting is dynamic, but the keys are not. The values for the keys  processorStatusSnapshot is always a dictionary, the key processGroupStatusSnapshots always a list which stores processorStatusSnapshot dictionaries and processGroupStatusSnapshots list.

Comment: Okay. In that case "GetFTP" should not be printed.

Comment: Actually, `processGroupStatusSnapshot` is a dictionary, and `processGroupStatusSnapshots` is a list. `processorStatusSnapshot` occurs only once in the dict.

Comment: Yes, if processorStatusSnapshots list has 10 items then there will be 1 processorStatusSnapshot dictionarys for each item.

Comment: To be honest, the key names are so similar it is very confusing for someone looking at this problem for first time :) I would recommend that you modify your data little bit next time before posting a question. Anyways, I am sharing a solution below, please feel free to modify based on your further requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the nesting, and the fact that key names will remain same in all levels, I think a recursive solution will work best here. Please feel free to use this solution as reference and modify based on your needs.

Argument `d` is the dictionary here.

```py
def find_name(d):
    if 'processGroupStatusSnapshot' in d:
        print("Name =", d['processGroupStatusSnapshot']['name'])
        nxt = d['processGroupStatusSnapshot']['processGroupStatusSnapshots']
        if len(nxt) > 0:
            find_name(nxt[0])

find_name(d)
```

Comment: Thanks you soo much Supratim Haldar

Comment: Please accept the answer, if it solved your problem